# How do i get the instant messaging addresses from iphone contacts

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do i get the instant messaging addresses from iphone contacts in my application ? Do you have a sample code for this, i know how to get the rest of the Data i just have problems whit this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW3) (search Personal Information Properties), you can't. Maybe you will be able to do it when (if) we will get access to the FaceTime API's.